# ERROR Cannot find the browser. "chrome" is neither a known browser alias, nor a path to an executable file. Type "testcafe -h"

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install chromedriver
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 4444

CMD ["npm", "run", "test:register"]

Comment: This information is insufficient to find the cause of the issue. Most probably, you do not have Chrome installed in your container. Try to use the official TestCafe docker image: [https://testcafe.io/documentation/402838/guides/advanced-guides/use-testcafe-docker-image](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402838/guides/advanced-guides/use-testcafe-docker-image)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
In my case, I was trying to run testcafe firefox:headless on bitbucket, and got this error. Later on I realised that I had 'chrome' listed as a browser on .testcaferc.json.